# How to position something left of dynamic content in React native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to position an icon to the left of some text in RN. but I have some problems

- The text can be of various lengths
- The text must be centered at all times
- The icon sometimes shows and sometimes is hidden, in both states it must not alter the position of the text

I've tried absolute positioning but that doesn't seem to work when text is of different sizes

I've tried flexbox but this always seems to alter the text position. i.e. it slightly moves when the icon is shown, then hidden

the only solution I've got is to have an invisible icon to the right hand side of the text which is the same width as the icon to the left. and that forces them all to align. It's not ideal and I'm hoping for a better solution. any better approaches?

Comment: why not just put a margin right on the text with the same size of the icon to the left?

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot.

Comment: @Christians methods worked well